# Image of p-group

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, p-groups

Let $G$ be a group and $|G|=p^n$ for some prime $p$. If $f:G\to H$ is a surjective homomorphism, how do I know $H=f(G)$ also has cardinality a power of $p$?

Comment: Do you mean $f(G)$?

Comment: what do you know about the kernel?

Comment: Do you mean to say that $H$ has cardinality a prime power of $p$? This is only true if you allow $p^0=1$ as well. Hint: Use the first isomorphism theorem.

Comment: Yes thanks @user3313320, I edited it

Comment: @ChristianSievers it's a normal subgroup of $G$ and its cardinality divides the cardinality of $G$ by Lagrange, so $|\ker f|=p^k$ for some $k\leq n$. So $G/\ker f\cong H$ has cardinality $p^n/p^k$. Does that work? I'm not sure if we always have $|K/L|=|K|/|L|$. Is that true?

Comment: That's exactly what I meant.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you familiar with the first isomorphism theorem? It says $f(G)\cong G/\ker f$, so $|f(G)|=|G/\ker f|=[G:\ker f]=|G|/|\ker f|$, which divides $G$.

Comment: Where does the very last equality follow from?

Comment: It's a standard result to show in an introductory group theory class that if $H$ is a subgroup of a finite group $G$ then $[G:H]=|G|/|H|$.

Answer (score 0):

Its a simple lemma to prove that for any homomorphism $f$, $ord(f(g))$ divides $ord(g)$. Since every element of $G$ has order a power of $p$,so must. $f(g)$ have order equal to a power of $p$.

As $f$ is surjective, this means every element of $H$ has order equal to a power of $p$ and hence $H$ is a finite $p$ group.

Comment: Why does every element of $G$ have order a power of $p$? Being a p group just means that the cardinality is a power of $p$ right?

Comment: For finite groups, these are equivalent. One way is just lagranges theorem (order of an element divides order of the group) and the other probably uses Cauchys theorem that says if some other prime $q$ divided the cardinality then we would have an element of order $q$.

Answer (score 0):

By Lagrange theorem $|\ker f|$ divides $G$. Hence $\ker f$ is a $p$-group. It follows $G/\ker f$ is also a $p$-group. By isomorphism theorem $G/ker f$ isomorphic to $f(G)$. Hence $f(G)$ is a $p$-group as well.